# Best way to create and store a Dynamic widget

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a "hosted form" widget (PHP, jquery, MySql), the widget will be customize by the users dynamically, multiple HTML inputs, different font, sizes, colors, etc. I was thinking to store the widget code (style and HTML code) in a text field on MySQL DataBase, is this the best way to this?
Something simple like:

or should I create one field for every element created?

Answer (score 0):

it's better store serialize information in text field insted of seprate table, because 1 query   saved and your application going faster